# Ubuntu 18.10 Slack not working

Tags: 18.10, slack

I've updated to Ubuntu 18.10 yesterday.
Now I can't find a version of Slack which isn't crashing.
Tried the version from snap and also the download from the site.
Has someone found a working version?

Answer (score 14):

Looks as if there's problem in the underlying electron app: Every electron based app is affected atm.

So i suggest to wait for an updated slack app and use the web interface in the meanwhile.

Comment: here is more info on it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1790966

Comment: wow.. that's hard.
They released a new Ubuntu version on which no electron based app is running.
Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Talk about not testing your code...I mean they didn't even run it once or they would have seen the blatant segfault

Comment: In the meantime there is a solution. The problem is in the outdated version of /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so.   You can replace it. One way if you already use VSCode or Atom: `sudo ln -sf /usr/share/code/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so`. For atom just replace `code` with `atom` in the path.

Comment: You can also find other instances of libnode.so in your system with: `sudo updatedb && locate libnode`

Comment: All electron apps are not affected. I have the same issue with slack after the upgrade to 18.10, but I have two others electron based apps working.

Comment: @mxlian Could you please upload your libnode.so somewhere ?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like same issue on question I've answered [early](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088959/561295).

Slack v3.3.1 stopped working after update Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10 yesterday. Tried update to v3.3.3 with no luck. Both Official Slack deb versions.

Tried run Slack from terminal and it just prints `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53086224/5938182), Slack came back to work:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so.bad
sudo ln -s /usr/share/atom/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so
```

Comment: I tried the same workaround with libnode from postman and insomnia installations, but it was not succeed with an other error. Those versions of libnode do not seem to be compatible with slack `/usr/lib/slack/slack: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/slack/slack: undefined symbol: udata_setCommonData_59`.

Comment: Could you please upload your libnode.so somewhere ?

Comment: libnode from skype worked, libnode from discord didn't

Comment: This worked as a charm, but using `code` instead of `atom`

Comment: Of the 12-odd versions of libnode.so on my system, only the one from /snap/skype/60/ libnode.so worked for me... including 2 other skype versions.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I tried some repositories and the .deb package () without success. So, I uninstalled the application, restart (I suppose is not necessary) and installed slack by snap:

```
sudo snap install slack --classic
```

And... the snap installation runs correctly

Comment: In my case it just throws me back to the login screen.

Comment: this works for me, but it takes a very long time to open slack... but better than not opening it at all. hopefully slack will fix this soon on their part

Comment: works for me too, I didn't need to restart...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, glibc 2.28 causes a segfault (Fedora 29 and other latest/beta distros are affected for the most part). It should be fixed in the next release.

In the meantime, switch to slack 3.1.1 or downgrade glibc to 2.27-3.

Answer (score 0):

Has the same probleme!
Launched slack on terminal and saw that it was already lauch so the app was never initialising storage.
All i did was killed the slack process by doing `killall slack` and after that it all worked fine.