# Slack 3.3.3 crash on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: deb, 18.10, debug, slack

I have installed the latest Slack 3.3.3 from the official website. Downloaded the deb package, but when i start it, it simply crash and nothing happens. It was working fine on Ubuntu 18.04. Is there a way to debug why this app its not working? Thanks!

[Link where i downloaded slack from](https://slack.com/downloads/linux)

When trying to run slack with `sudo snap run slack` i am getting those errors

> mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
>   No protocol specified
>
> (spotify:5309): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

and when i run it without `sudo` my whole system crash and restarts by itself.

**UPDATE**
I wrote to slack and this is what they have answered me

> Thanks for getting in touch, and I'm sorry for the troubles with Slack
>   on Ubuntu 18.10.
>
> We're aware of the issue, and we're already working on a solution.
>   We're confident that we'll be able to put out a version update with a
>   fix very soon. Sorry for the inconvenience here.

Comment: `snap run hello` outputs `Hello, World!` like it suppose to, but slack and spotify dosent work (i havent tried others snaps)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same here after update Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10 yesterday.

Slack v3.3.1 stopped working. Tried update to v3.3.3 with no luck.
Both Official Slack deb versions.

Trying run Slack from terminal, just prints `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53086224/5938182), Slack came back to work:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so.bad
sudo ln -s /usr/share/atom/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so
```

Comment: it's a good workaround. it worked for me. so basicly the idea is to take the `libnode.so` file from atom and create symbolic link to slack and use the same file. nice!

Comment: If you dont have atom you can still find another suitable library in your sistem with: `sudo updatedb && locate libnode`. I use the one from VSCode, without installing atom

Comment: just found on another thread:
"For Slack users who replaced libnode.so from somewhere else (and got the app running again) but still get the occasional crash, disable your notification sound for now.

It seems if Slack tries to play the notification sound for a new message, it simply restarts instead of ever getting around to playing the clip."

Comment: now every time i receive a message in Slack my Slack crash and then restarts which is super annoying so i am waiting for the official fix

Comment: Switching libnode.so works but Slack still has some crash when playing some audio. For me best solution was to roll back to 3.1.1 https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-3.1.1-amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

Basically, glibc 2.28 causes a segfault (Fedora 29 and other latest/beta distros are affected for the most part). It should be fixed in the next release.

In the meantime, switch to slack 3.1.1 or downgrade glibc to 2.27-3.

Comment: i just tested out with slack 3.1.1 and i can confirm it is working. you can download this version from https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/network/slack/